# React TypeError : cyclic object value nested

Tags: json, reactjs, nested, stringify

I'm kinda blocked on this one :

This is the state for my component :

```
state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword:'',
            birthDate: '',
            firstName: '',
            gender: '',
            preferences : {
                genderSearched: '',
                ageSearched: {
                    min: '',
                    max: ''
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like to send a request to my API by using fetch, so i've got my const here :

```
const {email, password, confirmPassword, birthDate, firstName, gender, preferences} = this.state;
```

And here it's what i'm trying to stringify

```
body: JSON.stringify({ email, password, confirmPassword, birthDate, firstName, gender, preferences})
```

I'm conscious that the problem is from preferences because it's only attribute that is truly nested but I don't know how handle it.

Cordially,

**EDIT** : I forgot to precise that I valorize these fields by using onChange method on inputs to setState these attributes. I don't think the problem is from the setState or maybe the one for ageSearched

Here is a bit more code for a better understanding :

```
onChangeAgeMinPreferences = (value) => {
        let preferences = {...this.state.preferences};
        preferences.ageSearched.min = value;
        this.setState({preferences})
    }

onChangeAgeMaxPreferences = (value) => {
        let preferences = {...this.state.preferences};
        preferences.ageSearched.max = value;
        this.setState({preferences})
    }

<Input value={this.state.preferences.ageSearched.min} onChange={this.onChangeAgeMinPreferences}></Input>

<Input value={this.state.preferences.ageSearched.max} onChange={this.onChangeAgeMaxPreferences}></Input>
```

Comment: You don't have a cyclic object value from the simple empty state you have shown, if it would be cyclic, you would have a child somewhere referring back to a parent in one of his properties, but I don't see that here. When you update the state, are you sure you are doing it correct? Are you also sure this is the info in your state at the moment you call stringify?

Comment: What is the expected payload that you want to send to your API endpoint ?

Comment: This might shed some light on the error... The code that you've provided seems fine - it must be someplace else... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value